# installing sampleSelection package in R

Tags: r

I am currently running R 3.2.4 on windows 10. I have been trying for several days to install the sampleSelectio package without success. i am new in R and I don't know what else to do. i have uinstalled and reinstaled R from version 2.9 to version 3.2.4. but still can't install the sampleSelection package. i keep getting this message:

```
> install.packages("sampleSelection")
```

Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/baby/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependencies ‘VGAM’, ‘mvtnorm’ are not available

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
                binary source needs_compilation
sampleSelection  1.0-4  1.2-6             FALSE

installing the source package ‘sampleSelection’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/sampleSelection_1.2-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3068830 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

ERROR: dependencies 'VGAM', 'mvtnorm' are not available for package 'sampleSelection'
* removing 'C:/Users/baby/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/sampleSelection'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4RE/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\baby\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\baby\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYndmKc/downloaded_packages/sampleSelection_1.2-6.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sampleSelection’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\baby\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYndmKc\downloaded_packages’

> 

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded in installing the sampleSelection package. one plausible explanation is that somme packages are built under different versions of R and somme packages are linked or depend on other packages available in different versions of R.  Thus sometimes it is necessary to update our versions of R or downgrade it depending on what package we want to use. 
The sampleSelection package depends on VGAM and mvtnorm which are under R 3.4.1 and R 3.5.0 respectively. Thus after instaling R 3.5.0, i installed the packages VGAM, mvtnorm and systemfit, miscTools, Ecdat to avoid the error i kept getting only after installing VGAM and mvtnorm.

Thereafter we can successfully >**install.packages("sampleSelection")**

Sorry if my explanation will seem a little bit confusing.
Thank you